# Get all members from buddypress with avatars

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get all members from my buddypress website with a normal mysql query and not using wordpress ones . But the problem is there are two tables in which the data is stored .

wp_bp_xprofile_fields

wp_bp_xprofile_data

The results which comes are like

for wp_bp_xprofile_data

[image]

and for wp_bp_xprofile_fields

[image]

The result i expect

```
User_id first_name  last_name   skills      email              avatar 

  1       example    example     any   demo@example.com       1234.jpeg
```

But all the fields i expect are as a values in wp_bp_xprofile_fields .

Comment: Avatars and avatar metadata are **not** stored in the database. You could gather user IDs and then run them through a custom function.  More info: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174447/how-to-get-all-users-that-uploaded-avatars-or-have-gravatars/174469#174469

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i wanted to get it through custom mysql query . Is there any way to establish that ?

Comment: How can you use mysql if avatar info is not stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Buddypress does not record avatar data or cover images to MySQL database.

There is only one way (not ideal):

- You have to use the `scandir()` or some other function to pick up all and only folder names at the location `/wp-content/uploads/avatars`
- You will get a list of numeric folder names. That's user ID's
- Compare that ID's in MySQL database and fetch users
- (optional) - You also can store some metadata for each user during this query to can later easy loop profiles with avatars

WARNING: You also need to check if the folder containing the avatar is empty or not. If it is empty then you have no avatar.